# Why the datanode of Apache IoTDB becomes readonly mode after running for a period of time?

Tags: time-series, readonly, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After running Apache IoTDB for a period of time, the datanode automatically becomes `readonly` mode. What may be the reason for this? I tried to manually call and execute `flush` command, and this will also cause the datanode to become `readonly`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the log of the corresponding datanode of Apache IoTDB and search for `readonly` keyword. It may be that the encoding format of the data is wrong, so you can check the log to certify that.